# How to display <a href> long text with fix width

Tags: html, css

I have horizontally alien html -list with fix width and each list have  some time text within  is longer and I need to overflow text to next line but without scrollbar.

### html

```css
  ul.horizontal-funtions-list{
      list-style-type: none;
      width: 100%;
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      margin: 0;
      overflow-x:auto;
      white-space: nowrap;
      background-color: blueviolet;
     }

    ul.horizontal-funtions-list li{
     display: inline-block;
     zoom:1;
     width: 100px;
     margin-left: 20px;
     padding: 20px;
     background-color: greenyellow;
    }

    ul.horizontal-funtions-list li a{
      display: block;
      width: 80px;
      color:gray;
    }
```

```html
  <ul class="horizontal-funtions-list">
        <li><a href="#Function A">I am long function name</a></li>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>          
    </ul>
```

I have tried display: block in ul.horizontal-funtions-list li a but its not working out

Comment: why have you got white-space nowrap if you want it to wrap?  Just remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ul.horizontal-funtions-list li a {
  display: block;
  color:gray;
  white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */    
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
  white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */    
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */    
  word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */

  /* OPTIONAL - FIXED height
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
  */
}
```

Note the `width` got removed.
Here is a snippet demonstrating the output.

```css
ul.horizontal-funtions-list{
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x:auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: blueviolet;
 }

ul.horizontal-funtions-list li{
 display: inline-block;
 zoom:1;
 width: 100px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: greenyellow;
}

ul.horizontal-funtions-list li a{
  display: block;
  color:gray;
  white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */    
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
  white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */    
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */    
  word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="horizontal-funtions-list">
    <li><a href="#Function A">I am long function name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>          
</ul>
```

Comment: my text wrapping is working fine, but following code kick list height problem, even then I give fix height I get different top-margin alignment as shown in code snippet

Comment: any solution for that

Answer (score 1):

```css
     ul.horizontal-funtions-list{
      list-style-type: none;
      width: 100%;
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      margin: 0;
      overflow-x:auto;
      white-space: nowrap;
      background-color: blueviolet;
     }
    
    ul.horizontal-funtions-list li{
     display: inline-block;
     zoom:1;
     width: 100px;
     margin-left: 20px;
     padding: 20px;
     background-color: greenyellow;
    }
    
    ul.horizontal-funtions-list li a{
      display: block;
      width: 80px;
      color:gray;
      /*new style*/
      white-space: pre-wrap;
    }
```

```html
    <ul class="horizontal-funtions-list">
        <li><a href="#Function A">I am long function name</a></li>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>          
    </ul>
```

Only add this css code for `<a>` tag.. `white-space: pre-wrap;`

Try this code..

Comment: why not just remove it?

Answer (score 1):

#### Problems (and solutions)

- If you want your list to wrap, don't include `white-space: nowrap`.
- If you don't want a scrollbar, don't include `overflow-x: auto`.
- If you want list items to contain the text they have, don't set a fixed `width: 100px` on them (nor on the anchors, that had `width: 80px`, inside of them).

#### Demo

Where I mostly removed styles you had, and set appropriate `padding` and `margin` to get the spacing right.

```css
ul.horizontal-funtions-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 0;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.horizontal-funtions-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

ul.horizontal-funtions-list li a {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<ul class="horizontal-funtions-list">
  <li><a href="#Function A">I am long function name</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Function B">Another long function name</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Function C">Yet another</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Function D">We can keep going</a></li>
</ul>

<p>Space in between.</p>

<ul class="horizontal-funtions-list">
  <li><a href="#Function A">Shorter list</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home">Doesn't wrap</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

- remove white-space: nowrap;
- remove ul.horizontal-funtions-list li  width: 100px;
- change ul.horizontal-funtions-list li a   max-width:100px;

```css
ul.horizontal-funtions-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: auto;
    /* white-space: nowrap; */
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
ul.horizontal-funtions-list li {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    /* width: 100px; */
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: greenyellow;
}

ul.horizontal-funtions-list li a {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100px;
    color: gray;
}
```

```html
 <ul class="horizontal-funtions-list">
        <li><a href="#Function A">I am long function name</a></li>
        <li><a href="#home">I am long function name2</a></li>          
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the width property from the link and add `white-space: pre-wrap;`
Thats it.

```css
    ul.horizontal-funtions-list li a{
      /* width: 80px; */
      display: block;
      white-space: pre-wrap;
      color:gray;

    }
```

Comment: No. The `li` also has a set width.

Comment: Thats what he wants. He want a fix li with and the link should break into multiple lines